# Setting subscription period in developer mode for testing

Tags: stripe-payments

When I last used Stripe subscriptions in test mode, they only had a duration of a few minutes, which made it easy for testing.

It seems they have changed this, now the subscriptions have the actual period. I know there is Test Clock but I would prefer to have the previous behavior back. Is it possible to set the duration of the subscription for testing mode to something very short for testing?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which parameter you're referring to when you say `duration`, but the shortest period you can set the Price's [recurring.interval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-recurring-interval) to is one `day`.

Answer (score 0):

As of `17-10-2022`,

You can set minimum 1 day as test subscription interval.

If you want to test your stripe webhooks then you can use [stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test)